# creating dynamic unique email address pipes in cpanel with php

Tags: email, cpanel

Im trying to make something similar to twitpic.com's email submission feature.

Their address schema is something like username.key@twitpic.com. When you send an email to that address it processes it and uploads your picture.

What im wondering is how they generate and handle those addresses in php. I know how to pipe a single email address to a program using cpanel, but how is this done dynamically?

Ill settle on what this is even called or some google search results so i can do my own research, but i just want a place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option in cpanel to set a default address that catches all email sent to addresses that don't exist. This is probably the easiest way to do it.

In fact, in the version of cpanel I have, if you go to Default Address, and go to Advanced Options there an option to pipe to a program all mail without a valid address.

Comment: Im aware of this functionality, but i need to do this dynamically from a php script.

Comment: If you're piping ALL emails that aren't going to an existing mailbox, you can simply check the "to" address in php to see what email address it was addressed to, so there is no need to create for for every email address you need.

Comment: I see what your saying, much simpler approach. Im going to investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found this.
http://twiki.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/Api2AddForwarder
Trying to find out how/where i can do this using PHP

**update**
Found a cpanel api class here
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17045.html
Im trying to contact the author of the class to see how to add the functionality of the api to that class (which can already handle creation of forwarders)

Answer (score 0):

Juse copy and pase below code and replace the desired variables and it will be work :

```
/*Host Credentials*/
$host = "Host Name";
$port = "Port Number ex. 2083";
$HostUserName = "Your cpanel username";
$HostPassword = "Your cpanel password";
/*-------------------------*/

/*Email details which you want to create*/
$email = "email name which you want to create";
$domain = "Domain name on which you want to create the email for subdomain you can write ex. subdomain.domain.com";
$password = "Password for your email"
$quota = "limit which you want to assign for this account."
/*--------------------*/

$query = 'https://'.$host.':'.$port.'/frontend/x3/mail/doaddpop.html?email='.$email.'&domain='.$domain.'&password='.$password.'&quota='.$quota;
$curl = curl_init();                                 // Create Curl Object
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);       // Allow self-signed certs
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);       // Allow certs that do not match the hostname
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);               // Do not include header in output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);       // Return contents of transfer on curl_exec
$header[0] ="Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($HostUserName.":".$HostPassword) . "\n\r";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);     // set the username and password
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);             // execute the query
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: It appears this approach is not advised in the cpanel documentation